# get the next word after grep matching

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm using this command to retrieve the signal average power of a client connected to an Access Point:

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep -E 'Station|signal avg':
```

I got the following info:

**Station** "my_MAC_Address" (on wlan0)

**signal avg:**      -46 dBm

In bold is what I matches with grep and I just only want to get the word after that matching, i.e the MAC address and the number -46. 
I've been playing with awk but without success.
hope you can help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep -Po '(?<=Station\s|signal avg:\s)[^\s]*'
```

This regexp uses a so-called `lookbehind` syntax. You can read about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Example output:

```
00:11:22:33:44:55
-40
```

#### Update:

Thanks for voting this answer up. Now I know another solution:

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep -Po '(Station\s|signal avg:\s)\K[^\s]*'
```

Which is actually a shorthand for the solution above. `\K` basically means "forget everything before its occurance".

Comment: +1. Method noted. Btw I think you forgot the other `'` at the end.

Comment: @konsolebox yes, ``'`` was missing, thanks! Unfortunately, very few people know about lookaround feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two grep to do this as well

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep -E 'Station|signal avg' | grep -o [^'Station|signalavg'].*
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible awk solution which plays fast and loose with whitespace is:

```
... | awk '$1 == "Station" { print $2 } 
           $1 $2 == "signalavg:" { print $3 }'
```