# How can I get next word after matching chars inside file

Tags: shell, sed, grep, sh

I've been searching for the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971765/using-grep-to-get-the-next-word-after-a-match-in-each-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708849/get-the-next-word-after-grep-matching) but no luck, I found a thread that discussing similar case with mine and eventually I decided to ask a question here, because it does not provide a solution to the case that I face.

How can I get a certain word in Python scripts (value of params) using bash script? for example, I have a Python script which has the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
...


args = {
    ...
}

# A DAG for my_bigquery_pipeline -> this line should not be included in bash searching.
with DAG(dag_id='my_bigquery_pipeline', default_args=args,
         schedule_interval='00 21 * * *') as dag:
```

from the above script I want to get the word `my_bigquery_pipeline` whose line is not commented on, before I ask here, I've tried it with the following way:

```
sed -n '/^.*dag_id\s\+\/\(\w\+\).*$/s//\1/p' bigquery_pipeline.py
// and
sed "s/dag_id//2g" bigquery_pipeline.py
// and
egrep -oP '(?<=dag_id=/)\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

unfortunately those method doesn't work for me, any help I'll appreciate! thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep` equals `grep -E`, so it will conflict with `-P` switch.
If you have GNU grep, you can do this:

```
grep -oP '(?<=dag_id=.)\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

or more exact:

```
grep -oP '(?<=dag_id=\x27)\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

Where `0x27` is `'`'s ascii code.
You can also change the outer quotes, like this:

```
grep -oP "(?<=dag_id=')\w+" bigquery_pipeline.py
```

or this more compatible with your `.py` code way:

```
 grep -oP 'dag_id\s*=\s*[\x27\x22]\K\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

Which will also match `dag_id = "my_bigquery_pipeline"`, and give result `my_bigquery_pipeline` .

And `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/^.*dag_id *= *[[:punct:]]\([[:alnum:]_]*\).*/s//\1/p' bigquery_pipeline.py
my_bigquery_pipeline
```

To avoid commented lines:

```
grep -oP '^\s*[^#]+.*dag_id\s*=\s*[\x27\x22]\K\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

or

```
sed -n '/^[^#]*dag_id *= *[[:punct:]]\([[:alnum:]_]*\).*/s//\1/p' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

And a `perl` solution for optional `dag_id=` and also ignore commented lines:

```
perl -nle 'print $& while m{[^#]*with DAG\((dag\s*=\s*)?[\x27\x22]\K\w+}g' bigquery_pipeline.py
```

Comment: Thanks! @Tiw works like a charm, but, how I identify if the line had commented? let say I hove 2 line of code like this: ```# DAG(dag_id='bebigquery', default_args=args,``` and ```with DAG(dag_id='belajar_bigquery', default_args=args,``` how can I get only the second one?

Comment: Yes! this is my right solution from you: ```sed -n '/^[^#]*dag_id *= *[[:punct:]]\([[:alnum:]_]*\).*/s//\1/p' bigquery_pipeline.py``` thank you @Tiw you're my hero :D

Comment: Hi! @Tiw, I have a new problem here (sorry if I bothering you), actually the keyword `dag_id=` is optional, there is a case where keyword `dag_id=` is not included, how can I make optional pattern? I know, I can do this with ```sed -n '/^[^#]*DAG *( *[[:punct:]]\([[:alnum:]_]*\).*/s//\1/p' bigquery_pipeline.py```, but is there a simple way to do this? thanks

Comment: @ImamDigmi  `grep -oP '[^#]*with DAG\((dag\s*=\s*)?[\x27\x22]\K\w+' bigquery_pipeline.py`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Tiw, I'm trying to find an alternative of `-P`, because the grep command on OSX doesn't support that option.

Comment: @ImamDigmi `brew install grep --with-default-names` , from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231370/installed-gnu-grep-on-osx-but-cant-use).

Comment: yes, OSX has perl preinstalled, thanks Tiw, this is final solution from you, many many thanks for you Tiw!